# How to hide one of the two Right buttons in the navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

Dear all I have implemented two buttons in the navigation bar on the right side on top of a text view as;

```
UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]
                      initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 112, 44.5)];

// toolbar style is the default style

// create an array for the buttons

NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

// create a button to run the job
UIBarButtonItem *runButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"RUN"
                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                              target:self
                              action:@selector(runAs:)];
// Button style is the default style
[buttons addObject:runButton];
[runButton release];

// create a spacer between the buttons

UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                           initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
                           target:nil
                           action:nil];
[buttons addObject:spacer];
[spacer release];

// create a standard Edit/Done button with custom titles Edit/Save

self.editButtonItem.possibleTitles = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Edit", @"Save", nil];
self.editButtonItem.title = @"Edit";
UIBarButtonItem *editButton = self.editButtonItem;
[buttons addObject:editButton];
[editButton release];

// put the buttons in the toolbar and release them
[toolbar setItems:buttons animated:YES];
[buttons release];

// place the toolbar into the navigation bar as Right Button item
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                          initWithCustomView:toolbar];
[toolbar release];
```

Now in Edit mode I want to hide the RUN button and when the RUN button is in action I want the Edit button to be hidden. Can someone suggest me a way to do that without redefining the buttons in edit mode (like there is for the back/left button item setHidesBackButton:(BOOL) animated:(BOOL)) or any alternate method? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = (UIToolbar *) self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView;
UIBarButtonItem *runButton = (UIBarButtonItem *) [toolbar.items objectAtIndex: 0];
runButton.customView.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: Dear Jacob, Thanks for the reply. I have tried the above code but it gives an error "hidden is something not a structure or union" possibly because the "runButton" is not a UIButton, it is a UIBarButtonItem. [runButton setHidden:(BOOL)] does not work either but [runButton setEnabled:(BOOL)] works. Any further suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I needed to show/hide one of two buttons exclusively. I created a category on NSMutableArray, removed both buttons if they're in the array, then added each if necessary. You'll probably need to have the buttons as properties on your ViewController.

**NSMutableArray+Extensions**

```
@implementation NSMutableArray (Extensions)
-(bool)removeItemIfExists:(id)item {
    bool wasRemoved=false;
    for (int i=self.count-1;i>0;i--) {
        if([self objectAtIndex:i] == item){
            [self removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            wasRemoved = true;
        }
    }
    return wasRemoved;
}
@end
```

Call it using:

```
NSMutableArray *newLeftItems = [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems mutableCopy];
[newLeftItems removeItemIfExists:btnOne];
[newLeftItems removeItemIfExists:btnTwo];
if(someCondition) { 
    [newLeftItems insertObject:btnOne atIndex:1];
} else {
    [newLeftItems insertObject:btnTwo atIndex:1];
}
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:newLeftItems animated:true];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
-(void) changeBarButtonVisibility:(UIBarButtonItem*) barButtonItem visibility:(BOOL) shouldShow {
UIColor *tintColor = shouldShow == NO ? [UIColor clearColor] : nil;
[barButtonItem setEnabled:shouldShow];
[barButtonItem setTintColor:tintColor];
```

}

and call the above method and pass the bar button you want to hide

```
[self changeBarButtonVisibility:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems[0] visibility:NO];
[self changeBarButtonVisibility:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems[1] visibility:YES];
```